# PHP/MySQL strange character issue

Tags: mysql

I have a vanilla forum based forum website. Currently customizing it. Before few days it was working fine. I am observing strange characters with data in the database when I save things.
For example if i register a new user using `naseem@gmail.com` in the database it saves as `seem@gmail.com�`
naseem is stripped to seem and some strange character at the end of the string.

I cant figure it out. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Going to need more information than that.  What's the character set of the webpage and database?  What kind of processing is being done on the text?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Nothing, just dumping to database. InnoDB, utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: plz help. The system is based on MVC

Comment: Definitely going to need to see code.

Comment: Can you give some account of this account? Why usually it occure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the command line/terminal, makes sure you do "SET NAMES UTF8". That will set your connection to mysql to UTF8. This is different than your database being set to UTF8. Also make sure you terminal application itself is set to UTF8.

The diamond question mark is almost always an indication of UTF8 character that isn't being displayed correctly because of encoding settings.